# Dynamic root Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I have a software in which users can have many projects, and within those projects they can have a "favorite" project that will be loaded whenever they login if they have one.

I would like to have the path be "app.example.io" regardless if they have a favorite project or not. If they have no project i would like the path to be "app.example.io" but send them to the "projects/index" and if they do have a "favorite" project i would like the path to remain the same "app.example.io" but i would like to send them to the specific project "projects/:project_id".

Point is i want a way to have the url always be the same when they are logging in regardless if they have a "favorite" project or not.

```
  constraints subdomain: 'app' do
    namespace :users do

        devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations], controller: {passwords: 'passwords', sessions: 'sessions'}, path: '', path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'}

         authenticated do
          root to: "projects#show", as: :authenticated
        end

        unauthenticated do
          root to: "users/sessions#new", as: :unauthenticated
        end
      end

      devise_scope :user do
        root to: "projects#show"
      end
```

that is my route file and my sessions controller is:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout "login"

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)    
    if !current_users_user.project_id
    "/projects"
    else
    "/projects/#{current_users_user.project_id}"
    end 
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)     
    "/users/login"
  end 
end
```

Appreciate any help thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below

```
"/projects/#{current_users_user.projects[0].project_id}" #=> projects is the table name you can replace which you have
```

or you need to try to authenticate the projects controller

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

then redirect to projects index path after login where all projects for the current user they can show only current user projects

I think will help

Comment: What i have works right now.. what i want to do is not have "projects/:project_id" show in the url